# Make two document-librarys that shows documents from other document library

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online

I would like to add one big documentlibrary that stores all the documents, but then I would also like to have two more documentlibrarys that only shows some of the documents from the big library.How do I do it?

Example:
The big Library 1: doc1, doc2, picture 1, doc3, excel-file,

Library 2: doc1, doc2

Library 3: picture 2, exceldok, doc3

This is because then I can synkronice the small library(Library 2) instead of the big one.

Comment: Are these smaller libraries going to have unique documents that will not be in the large one? Or will they only have documents from the large one? If the latter, then you can simply create views instead of libraries.

Comment: No, it will be the same documents. But how can I synkronice just a part of the documentlibrary to my computer if I have views?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by synchronizing part of the library to your computer.  Do you want the documents in the large library not to be changed if edited in the smaller libraries?

Comment: No the documents should change in the large library if the documents changes in the smaller one. Okay let me put it this way instead: I want different librarys because I want different permissions.

Comment: You can use folders instead of libraries.  Create two folders in the big library, and use views to display the documents.